# Call LaTeX (not PDFLaTeX) in Miktex

Tags: miktex, dvi

I am a bit confused because in the "good old days", the command `latex` seemed to create a `dvi` document.

Now, when I run `latex`, obviously `pdflatex` is run, even if I specify an output format:

```
C:\Users\jfabi\OneDrive\LaTeX>latex previewTest.tex -output-format=dvi
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3)
```

Can somebody tell me how to generate a plain old `dvi` document from a `tex` source?

Comment: That's exactly what you will get using `latex <name>`: did you get a PDF? If so, something is up

Comment: @JosephWright You see my command line output? I said `latex` and it answers with `This is pdfTeX`.

Comment: pdftex can output both dvi and pdf. `latex` nowadays is `pdftex + format latex + output dvi`, while `pdflatex` is `pdftex + format latex + output pdf`.  So look what you get.

Comment: you don't need `-output-format=dvi` just using the command `latex` wil give you dvi (the banner will say pdftex as pdflatex and latex are the same binary)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for the clarification, I was just confused.